# Перебор массива с определенным шагом

Tags: c#, массивы, перебор

Для реализации кодирования Хемминга мне нужно перебрать исходное сообщение с определённым шагом (через 1, через 2 и т.д.). Как это реализовать в c#? Приложу то, что я написал (вряд ли поможет)

```cs
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите сообщение: ");
            string inMessage = Console.ReadLine();
            List<byte> sourceMessage = new List<byte>();
            for (int i = 0; i < inMessage.Length; i++)
                sourceMessage.Add(byte.Parse(inMessage[i].ToString()));
            byte[] correctBytes = new byte[Convert.ToByte(Math.Log(inMessage.Length, 2)) + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < correctBytes.Length; i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < sourceMessage.Count; i++)
                    correctBytes[i] = 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Превратить строку в массив лучше сразу: `byte[] sourceMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inMessage)`

`for(int j = 0; j < sourceMessage.Count; i++)` - почему `i`?  `j = j + 1` - через 1; `j = j + 2` - через 2 и т.д.

Comment: насчёт ```i``` ошибся просто. 
На вход идёт двоичный код, если преобразовывать строку в массив сразу, в массиве остаётся не двоичный код, а массив кодов элементов char, для этого я реализовал подобным способом